# How do you go to the next tab in schema form?

Tags: angular, forms, tabs, schema, angular-schema-form

I have an issue with schema form, may be you can help me, this is my form and I need to step from a tab to another one.

Is there a way to do this?

I have a bottom where I get the id from the tab, but I can´t make it jump to other tab.

```
"form": [
    {
        "type": "fieldset",
        "title": "Ficha Base",
        "items": [
            {
                "type": "tabs",
                "style": "padding-top: 5px;",
                "tabs": [
                    {
                        "title": "Datos Personales",
                        "id": "1",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "section",
                                "htmlClass": "row",
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "section",
                                        "htmlClass": "col-md-6 col-xs-12",
                                        "items": [
                                            {
                                                "type": "button",
                                                "style": "btn btn-primary",
                                                "title": "Enviar",
                                                "onClick": "siguientePestana('1')"
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "title": "Datos Académicos Enseñanza Superior",
                        "id": "2",
                        "items": [
                            {
                                "type": "section",
                                "htmlClass": "row",
                                "items": [
                                    {
                                        "type": "section",
                                        "htmlClass": "row",
                                        "items": [
                                            {
                                                "type": "section",
                                                "htmlClass": "col-md-12",
                                                "items": [
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "button",
                                                        "style": "btn btn-primary",
                                                        "title": "Enviar1",
                                                        "onClick": "siguientePestana('2')",
                                                        "condition": "model.ocultarCampo"
                                                    },
                                                    {
                                                        "type": "help",
                                                        "helpvalue": "<div class=\"alert alert-info\">Asegurece de entrar en con el perfil y fecha correcta para actualizar el formulario</div>",
                                                        "condition": "!model.ocultarCampo"
                                                    }
                                                ]
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: It's not really clear what you are having an issue with. Can you provide more information to help clarify what and where the issue is?

Comment: The scheme is missing. Test with something simpler like https://github.com/json-schema-form/angular-schema-form/blob/master/docs/index.md#tabs and comment please

Comment: Ok, testing with your same example, I´m trying to put a buttom at the end of the tabs so you can go from tab 1 to tab 2...  but I can´t :(